# How to maintain data integrity while allowing for real life changes?

Tags: database, normalization

In a new database model that I am designing, I have a **company** table that has a **contacts** table related to it using a foreign key **companyID** field.

I have a **branch** table with PK branchId and FK companyId.

The problem is: Sometimes contacts can move from the company or branch they are in to a different one. And I need to know all the former companies and branches the contact was in.

What is the best way to do this? 
I can't figure out anything that makes sense. If I insert another record into **contacts** with the different details, There will be a duplicate record, and if I just change the details, how will I know what the former details were?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a table that joins your contacts table to your company table. This new table would have a contactsid, a companyid, a date (or date range, depending on your needs) and any other info that you would need to describe the relationship between the contact and the company. The contacts table would then no longer need an FK companyID.